# Bezier gradient function instead of linear - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, graph, colors

I have made my own gradient generator in JavaScript and it works well. Using it, I made a rectangle that starts black and fades linearly to green. This is what it looks like:

[image]

The function finds the distance between the two inputted numbers (`a` and `b`), and then finds the average number based on the decimal put in. `decimal = 0.5` would be half way between `a` and `b`, but `decimal = 0.3` would be closer to `a`.

This is the function:

```
// Gradient Function
function linearGradient(a, b, decimal) {
    // find distance between a and b
    const dist = b - a

    /* if you multiply the distance by
    the decimal and add the minimum
    again, it gives you the point at
    which the decimal interacts with
    the number */
    return a + dist * decimal
}

/* ------- EXAMPLE USE ------- */

// Green & Black colour definition
const color_black = [0, 0, 0]
const color_green = [0, 255, 0]

// Make a for-loop to find the Red, Green and Blue values of each stage from black to green
const resolution = 20
for (let i = 0; i < resolution; i ++) {
    red = linearGradient(color_black[0], color_green[0], i / resolution)
    green = linearGradient(color_black[1], color_green[1], i / resolution)
    blue = linearGradient(color_black[2], color_green[2], i / resolution)
}
```

So, to put this into graphics, this is what the function does:

[image]

That's alright as it is, but the reason I made this function was for making a *smooth* or *bezier* gradient. At the moment this is a linear gradient - as it travels linearly from one point to the next. In graph terms, linear goes in a straight line, but bezier moves by speeding up gradually, reaching an average peak, and then slowing down:

[image]

What can I change in my function to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is well formatted, you show code and effort. What i don't understand is, what have you tried so far? What you want to do doesn't require terribly advanced math, and there are plenty of articles. You should have had a point to start, and accordingly some more specific point you got stuck at?

Comment: You could use an easing function.  Check https://easings.net/.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, I couldn't actually find _any_ articles regarding this problem (in vanilla JavaScript, that is). But if, mathematically, this is quite a simple task, then I would be more than happy for some example code or a link!

Comment: @James, thank you for the reference, it looks very interesting and quite promising. I will have a play and see if I can come up with anything.